# Postgresql change the timestamp to YYYYMMDD using to_char and proceed with the comparison via query in Fastapi

Tags: postgresql, fastapi

Postgresql change the timestamp to YYYYMMDD using to_char and proceed with the comparison via query in Fastapi

num variable is already Int type.

```
days = (datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y%m%d")

ex = session.execute("""SELECT * FROM tb WHERE num = %d AND TO_CHAR(updated_at, 'YYYYMMDD') >= %s""", (num, days))
```

error message

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

How should I modify the days variable?

Comment: Why don't you use a standard ISO format for your date? It looks like updated_at is already a date (or timestamp?) and you don't need TO_CHAR() at all and an ordinary index on updated_at could be beneficial as well. Using a non-standard format would make things more complex, error prone and most likely slower as well.

Comment: Yes, updated_at is already a timestamp type. What you are saying is that I can use updated_at as it is and compare without converting from datetime?

Comment: Yes, correct, there should be no need to convert your timestamp in the database to a piece of text

Comment: That error is a pure Python error, so I don't think the error is related to the Postgres query itself either - are you sure you've included the correct line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting the db value to your local format, you can use [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to convert that local format to db's regular `date` type:

```python
days = (datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y%m%d")
ex = session.execute("""SELECT * 
                        FROM tb 
                        WHERE num = %d 
                        AND updated_at >= to_date(%s,'YYYYMMDD')
                     """, (num, days) )
```

If your database time matches your client time, you could also use [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in the query and not have to check, format and pass it from the client at all.

Still, your message seems to be pointing elsewhere, because the operator `<` doesn't match the `>=` and `=` in your query, and the error comes from Python, not PostgreSQL. The message would be different, and the mismatched type would be `text`, not `str`.